# How to increase the speed for only 2 variable counters instead of all

Tags: javascript, html

I have 5 incrementing time counters. I only want 2 counters (for the Sales)to increase their speed when onload . Given how my code is structured, how can I achieve this?

Here is my js code below:

```
let hoursLabel= document.getElementById("hours");
let minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
let secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
let footwareSales =document.getElementById("footwareSales");
let footwareUnits = document.getElementById("footwareUnits");
let sneakersUnits= document.getElementById("sneakersUnits");
let sneakerSales=document.getElementById("sneakersSales");
let footwareSalesPerSecond =parseInt("8162");
let footwareUnitsPerSecond =parseFloat("388.7") ;
let sneakerSalesPerSecond=parseInt("2122");
let sneakerUnitsPerSeconds=parseInt("101");
let totalSeconds = 0;
let totalMinutes = 0;
let GlobalFootwareMarket=0;
let GlobalSneakerMarket=0;
let speed =100;   

setInterval(setTime, 1000);//every after one one second = 1000 milliseconds.

function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  GlobalFootwareMarket +=footwareSalesPerSecond;
  GlobalSneakerMarket += sneakerSalesPerSecond;
  footwareUnitsPerSecond +=footwareUnitsPerSecond/totalSeconds;
                sneakerUnitsPerSeconds+=sneakerUnitsPerSeconds/totalSeconds.toFixed(2); // trying to make this number be in 2 decimal places.

  secondsLabel.innerHTML = perSecond(totalSeconds % 60);
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = perSecond(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
  hoursLabel.innerHTML = perSecond(parseInt(totalMinutes)/60);

  footwareUnits.innerHTML=perSecond(++footwareUnitsPerSecond);
  sneakersUnits.innerHTML=perSecond(sneakerUnitsPerSeconds);
   sneakerSales.innerHTML=perSecond(GlobalSneakerMarket);
   footwareSales.innerHTML=perSecond(GlobalFootwareMarket);
  //speedUp(GlobalFootwareMarket,GlobalFootwareMarket);    
}

function perSecond(val) {
  let valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString;
  } else {
    return valString;
  }

  /* function for speeding totals:
  function speedUp(GlobalSneakerMarket,GlobalFootwareMarket){
    if ((GlobalSneakerMarket || GlobalFootwareMarket) > 1000){
      sneakerSales.innerHTML=perSecond(GlobalSneakerMarket);
      footwareSales.innerHTML=perSecond(GlobalFootwareMarket);
      speed *=speed;
    setTimeout(setTime, speed);
  }else{

  }
}    */ 

}
```

Here is my HTML code: (I am not sure if it's helpful at att)

```
<div>
            <label>H:M:S</label><br>
            <label id="hours">00</label>:<label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label>  <br>
          </div>

          <br>
          <div>
          <label>Total Global Footware Revenue per second $</label>
          <label id="footwareSales"></label><br>

            <label>Total Footware units sold per second</label> <label id="footwareUnits"></label><br>

          <label>Total Global Sneakers Revenue per second $</label>
            <label  id="sneakersSales"></label><br>
          <label  >Total sneakers units sold per second </label>
            <label id="sneakersUnits"></label>
          </div>
```

The 2 variables I want to change are the GlobalSneakerMarket and GlobalFootwareMarket

Comment: What do you mean increase speed? Do you mean you want to change the time interval when those variables need to be changed? Or the values in the variables themselves?

Comment: What I mean by increase speed ... so currently the counters starts normal (all showing values at the same pace)- I need only the 2 mentioned in questioned to  speed up by in showing their values. I think the first option not the last one.

Comment: When do you want to reduce the interval time ? At which level ?

Comment: @Weedoze : I have made some changes to my questions-- I want the changes to happen onload to only 2 counters

Comment: Can you have two separate setInterval?

Comment: @KalimahApps Yes, thanks, I tried. It Seems to work  a bit but the speeds are not running as fast as I hoped. Per second I wanted the sales counters (for both footwear and sneakers ) to hit 8162  and 2122 respectively. So in 1 second the footware sales should run as fast as possible to hit 8162 and the sneaker sales counter  should run fast enough to hit 2122 (both of them starting at 0). Thanks, your input is valueable, if you could get the timings of intervals to be as fast as I am explaining then I should accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to achieve what you want we need to use an external class "CountUp".

Also, a quick note: repeating code is not easy to maintain. You might want to use a function to reproduce the code.

Here is an example:

```js
let hoursLabel = document.getElementById("hours");
let minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
let secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
//let footwareSales = document.getElementById("footwareSales");
let footwareUnits = document.getElementById("footwareUnits");
let sneakersUnits = document.getElementById("sneakersUnits");
//let sneakerSales = document.getElementById("sneakersSales");
let footwareSalesPerSecond = parseInt("8162");
let footwareUnitsPerSecond = parseFloat("388.7");
let sneakerSalesPerSecond = parseInt("2122");
let sneakerUnitsPerSeconds = parseInt("101");
let totalSeconds = 0;
let totalMinutes = 0;
let GlobalFootwareMarket = 0;
let GlobalSneakerMarket = 0;
let speed = 100;

const options = {
  useEasing: false,
  useGrouping: false,
};

/* Add two counters one for footWareSales and one for sneakersSales
CountUp function takes these arguments: 
// target = id of html element or var of previously selected html element where counting occurs
// startVal = the value you want to begin at
// endVal = the value you want to arrive at
// decimals = number of decimal places, default 0
// duration = duration of animation in seconds, default 2
// options = optional object of options (see below)

var CountUp = function(target, startVal, endVal, decimals, duration, options) {}
*/

let footwareSalesFrom = 0;
let sneakersSalesFrom = 0;
let footwareSalesTo = footwareSalesPerSecond;
let sneakerSalesTo = sneakerSalesPerSecond;


setInterval(function() {
  const footwareSales = new CountUp('footwareSales', footwareSalesFrom, footwareSalesTo, 0, 1, options);
  footwareSales.start();

  const sneakrsSales = new CountUp('sneakersSales', sneakersSalesFrom, sneakerSalesTo, 0, 1, options);
  sneakrsSales.start();

  footwareSalesFrom = footwareSalesTo;
  sneakersSalesFrom = sneakerSalesTo;

  footwareSalesTo += footwareSalesPerSecond;
  sneakerSalesTo += sneakerSalesPerSecond;
}, 1000);

setInterval(setTime, 1000); //every after one one second = 1000 milliseconds.

function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  // GlobalFootwareMarket += footwareSalesPerSecond;
  //GlobalSneakerMarket += sneakerSalesPerSecond;
  footwareUnitsPerSecond += footwareUnitsPerSecond / totalSeconds;
  sneakerUnitsPerSeconds += sneakerUnitsPerSeconds / totalSeconds.toFixed(2); // trying to make this number be in 2 decimal places.

  secondsLabel.innerHTML = perSecond(totalSeconds % 60);
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = perSecond(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
  hoursLabel.innerHTML = perSecond(parseInt(totalMinutes) / 60);

  footwareUnits.innerHTML = perSecond(++footwareUnitsPerSecond);
  sneakersUnits.innerHTML = perSecond(sneakerUnitsPerSeconds);
  //sneakerSales.innerHTML = perSecond(GlobalSneakerMarket);
  // footwareSales.innerHTML = perSecond(GlobalFootwareMarket);
  //speedUp(GlobalFootwareMarket,GlobalFootwareMarket);    
}

function perSecond(val) {
  let valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString;
  } else {
    return valString;
  }

  /* function for speeding totals:
  function speedUp(GlobalSneakerMarket,GlobalFootwareMarket){
    if ((GlobalSneakerMarket || GlobalFootwareMarket) > 1000){
      sneakerSales.innerHTML=perSecond(GlobalSneakerMarket);
      footwareSales.innerHTML=perSecond(GlobalFootwareMarket);
      speed *=speed;
    setTimeout(setTime, speed);
  }else{

  }
}    */

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/countup@1.8.2/dist/countUp.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>H:M:S</label><br>
  <label id="hours">00</label>:<label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label> <br>
</div>

<br>
<div>
  <label>Total Global Footware Revenue per second $</label>
  <label id="footwareSales">0</label><br>

  <label>Total Footware units sold per second</label> <label id="footwareUnits"></label><br>

  <label>Total Global Sneakers Revenue per second $</label>
  <label id="sneakersSales"></label><br>
  <label>Total sneakers units sold per second </label>
  <label id="sneakersUnits"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: I will still make it maintainable, for now I just wanted a base to work from. Thanks, just a final thing - the Total Revenue per second counters should not stop. so far they are ok per 1 second, but they need to continue to increment every second and not just stop at one second. Every second they need to increment grow by the same value and speed I am not sure where to edit to achieve this.

Comment: You can set another time and few extra variables that increase each second. See my updated example.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your *"max level"* variables and add an if statement inside your function. I defined the max value for them to 100,000. Look at the example:

```js
let hoursLabel = document.getElementById("hours");
let minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
let secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
let footwareSales = document.getElementById("footwareSales");
let footwareUnits = document.getElementById("footwareUnits");
let sneakersUnits = document.getElementById("sneakersUnits");
let sneakerSales = document.getElementById("sneakersSales");
let footwareSalesPerSecond = parseInt("8162");
let footwareUnitsPerSecond = parseFloat("388.7");
let sneakerSalesPerSecond = parseInt("2122");
let sneakerUnitsPerSeconds = parseInt("101");
let totalSeconds = 0;
let totalMinutes = 0;
let GlobalFootwareMarket = 0;
let GlobalSneakerMarket = 0;
let GlobalFootwareMarketMaxLevel = 100000; // Max level variables
let GlobalSneakerMarketMaxLevel = 100000;
let speed = 100;

setInterval(setTime, 1000); //every after one one second = 1000 milliseconds.

function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  // IF statement to control GlobalFootwareMarket max level
  if(GlobalFootwareMarket <= GlobalFootwareMarketMaxLevel) GlobalFootwareMarket += footwareSalesPerSecond;
  // IF statement to control GlobalSneakerMarket max level
  if(GlobalSneakerMarket <= GlobalSneakerMarketMaxLevel) GlobalSneakerMarket += sneakerSalesPerSecond;
  footwareUnitsPerSecond += footwareUnitsPerSecond / totalSeconds;
  sneakerUnitsPerSeconds += sneakerUnitsPerSeconds / totalSeconds.toFixed(2); // trying to make this number be in 2 decimal places.

  secondsLabel.innerHTML = perSecond(totalSeconds % 60);
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = perSecond(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
  hoursLabel.innerHTML = perSecond(parseInt(totalMinutes) / 60);

  footwareUnits.innerHTML = perSecond(++footwareUnitsPerSecond);
  sneakersUnits.innerHTML = perSecond(sneakerUnitsPerSeconds);
  sneakerSales.innerHTML = perSecond(GlobalSneakerMarket);
  footwareSales.innerHTML = perSecond(GlobalFootwareMarket);
  //speedUp(GlobalFootwareMarket,GlobalFootwareMarket);    
}

function perSecond(val) {
  let valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString;
  } else {
    return valString;
  }

  /* function for speeding totals:
  function speedUp(GlobalSneakerMarket,GlobalFootwareMarket){
    if ((GlobalSneakerMarket || GlobalFootwareMarket) > 1000){
      sneakerSales.innerHTML=perSecond(GlobalSneakerMarket);
      footwareSales.innerHTML=perSecond(GlobalFootwareMarket);
      speed *=speed;
    setTimeout(setTime, speed);
  }else{
     
  }
}    */

}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>H:M:S</label><br>
  <label id="hours">00</label>:<label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label> <br>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <label>Total Global Footware Revenue per second $</label>
  <label id="footwareSales"></label><br>
  <label>Total Footware units sold per second</label> <label id="footwareUnits"></label><br>
  <label>Total Global Sneakers Revenue per second $</label>
  <label id="sneakersSales"></label><br>
  <label>Total sneakers units sold per second </label>
  <label id="sneakersUnits"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: in your example, when they reach 100000, they stop and before they reach your max -their speed remains the same. What I want, drawing from our example, is for them to speed up first (maybe at 30 000 - and keep running a bit faster then other clocks)before stopping when they reach the max. Thanks for this input